What is the recommended approach to setting up social login for Azure apps?
I have a simple function app that hosts a JSON-RPC endpoint on Azure. That endpoint is called from a native CLI application. Now I want to build authentication and authorization for it that allows for:

Social login using Discord
Granular authorization (control user permissions depending on method in JSON-RPC call)
Clean function code. Prefarably all authentication and authorization should be handled early in the stack.

I am decently familiar with the infrastructure side for setting up the function app and CI/CD stuff, but I'm having trouble getting a good overview of how Azure authentication/authorization works with APIM, App Registrations, OAuth, OIDC, B2C and Identity Experience Framework.
I currently don't see a straight forward way to set this up using Azure built in products.
My current test setup uses Azure API Management (APIM) and a B2C tenant where the application is registered.
In APIM I already have my function app registered as an API and I intend to have a inbound validate-jwt policy for authentication and an inbound processing rule for authorization (written with friendly support from GPT):
    <!-- Step 2: Extract JSON-RPC Method from Body -->
    <set-variable name="jsonRpcBody" value="@{context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true)}" />
    <set-variable name="jsonRpcMethod" value="@{
        var body = context.Variables["jsonRpcBody"];
        var jsonObj = JsonDocument.Parse(body);
        return jsonObj.RootElement.GetProperty("method").GetString();
    }" />
    
    <!-- Step 3: Conditional Authorization Based on Method -->
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables["jsonRpcMethod"] == "method.read")">
            <!-- Authorize Read Method -->
            <check-claim name="scp" failed-check-httpcode="403" failed-check-error-message="Forbidden. The required scope for read method is missing." match="any">
                <value>method.read</value>
            </check-claim>
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables["jsonRpcMethod"] == "method.write")">
            <!-- Authorize Write Method -->
            <check-claim name="scp" failed-check-httpcode="403" failed-check-error-message="Forbidden. The required scope for write method is missing." match="any">
                <value>method.write</value>
            </check-claim>
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables["jsonRpcMethod"] == "method.admin")">
            <!-- Authorize Admin Method -->
            <check-claim name="roles" failed-check-httpcode="403" failed-check-error-message="Forbidden. You do not have the required admin role." match="any">
                <value>Admin</value>
            </check-claim>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <!-- Default Forbidden if method is not recognized -->
            <return-response response-message="Forbidden. The method is not recognized." status-code="403" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>

I'm not there yet though because I need to obtain a JWT to validate first. For that I have an Azure B2C tenant where I configured my own app registration and an IEF custom policy for a SignUpAndSignin user flow. The full IEF policy can be found here: https://pastebin.com/f2BfVr6C
The entire policy is pretty much just adapted from a Microsoft Sample and I have no clue what most of it does in detail. In general it's working, but I have 2 open problems:

I don't see how I can extend the SelfAsserted claims with custom attributes
I don't see how I can pass additional claims in the token to include authorization information

While I would appreciate any help in regards to these problems my main question is actually just if I'm on the right track? This whole setup seems very complicated for what I thought would be a straightforward setup. Is this how it's usually done? Are there alternatives?

can you please specify what do you want to achieve using APIM policy? please specify your requirement by giving some examples

Gladly! The APIM policy is intended for authorization. So I have one RPC endpoint able to execute different actions but not every user should be able to execute every function. So the APIM policy is supposed to read the request body, extract the method called and then check if the caller posses a given claim that allows them to call the function

Can you please share one example of your requirement like a request body expected response from APIM policy

Please share a sample xml data for testing purpose

Two problems which you have mentioned in question, I believe you need to make changes in the xml file instead of APIM policy
